# How to narrow Typescript Types autogenerated by graphQL codegen?

Tags: typescript, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I get a TypeScript type autogenerated from AWS-Amplify GraphQL (which uses apollo-codegen I believe) like such:

```
export type GetNoteQuery = {
  getNote:  {
    __typename: "Note",
    id: string,
    createdAt: string | null,
    updatedAt: string | null,
    title: boolean | null,
    content: string | null,
  } | null,
```

I want to generate a base type of "Note" to use as "base" type to use in my code when using the returned data. I.e. mapping notes onto a React component, etc.

Is there a way to narrow this type that is auto generated, or to extend it in some way, to have it look like:

```js
type Note = {
    id: string,
    createdAt: string | null,
    updatedAt: string | null,
    title: boolean | null,
    content: string | null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an index query to get the type of `getNote` coupled with `Exclude` to get rid of the the `null` from the property type. You then can use `Omit` to get rid of the extra property.

```
export type GetNoteQuery = {
  getNote: {
    __typename: "Note",
    id: string,
    createdAt: string | null,
    updatedAt: string | null,
    title: boolean | null,
    content: string | null,
  } | null
}

type Note = Omit<Exclude<GetNoteQuery['getNote'], null>, '__typename'>
```

You can also use an interface to get a stronger name for the type:

```
interface Note extends Omit<Exclude<GetNoteQuery['getNote'], null>, '__typename'> { }
```

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by using an interface to "get a stronger name for the type"?

Comment: @StephenA.Lizcano type aliases get expanded in errors and tooltips, so you might see something like `Pick<Exclude<.... ` instead of `Note`. Interface names are always preserved.

Answer (score 2):

GraphQL-Codegen creator here.

Just some background on the decision to generate this kind of TS code:
We started `typescript` as a plugin for creating an exact representation of the GraphQL schema.
Then, `typescript-operations` take operations and fragments (that picks specific fields and data from the schema) and generates code that takes the same fields and data fields from the generated types by `typescript` plugin.

We saw some developers prefer cleaner code, so you can use `preResolveTypes: true` to avoid using `Pick` and just use the primitive type in-place.
You can also use `onlyOperationTypes: true` in order to tell the codegen to avoid generating types that are not needed.

Comment: Appreciate your answer @dotan! Will definitely try asap and provide feedback, seems really usable for us.